# Fast Fourier transform of the recorded wav file in Android

Tags: android, fft, wav, analysis

There is a wav file on SD card. First, I connect to a file and reads the byte:

```
File file = null;file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/202.wav");
       byte[] byteData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
       FileInputStream in = null;
       try {
       in = new FileInputStream( file );
       in.read( byteData );
       in.close();}
```

I then use the transformation of data from a byte type in type double, because the FFT procedure does not work with byte type:

```
double[] transformed = new double[(int) file.length()];
      for (int j=1;j<8194;j++) {
              transformed[j] = (double)byteData[j]; }
```

And then the procedure of FFT processing this data:

```
public void spektr(double[] x, double[] y, int Dim, int D, double[] xx, double[] yy) {

     int I,J,N,L,K,LE,LE1,IP,NV2,NM1;
     double Arg,U1,U2,U3,C,S,T1,T2,T3,T4;


     N = (int) Math.pow(2,Dim);
     Log.v("N", "N "+N);
     for (L = 1; L < Dim; L++){
      LE = (int) Math.pow(2,Dim+1-L);
      LE1 = LE/2;
      U1 = (double)1.0;
      U2 = (double)0.0;
      Arg = (double)Math.PI/LE1;
      C = (double)Math.cos(Arg);
      S = D*(double)Math.sin(Arg);
      for(J = 1; J < LE1; J++){
       I = J;
       do{
            IP = I+LE1;
            T1 = x[I] + x[IP];
            T2 = y[I] + y[IP];
            T3 = x[I] - x[IP];
            T4 = y[I] - y[IP];
            x[IP] = T3*U1 - T4*U2;
            y[IP] = T4*U1 + T3*U2;
            x[I] = T1;
            y[I] = T2;
            I = I + LE;
       }while(I <= N);
       U3 = U1*C - U2*S;
       U2 = U2*C - U1*S;
       U1 = U3;
      }

     }

     NV2 = N / 2;
     Log.v("NV2", "NV2 "+NV2);
     NM1 = N-1;
     Log.v("NM1", "NM1 "+NM1);
     J = 1;
     for(I = 1; I < NM1; I++){
      if (I < J){
       T1 = x[J];
       T2 = y[J];
       x[J] = x[I];
       y[J] = y[I];
       x[I] = T1;
       y[I] = T2;
      }
      K = NV2;
      while (K < J){
       J = J - K;
       K = K / 2;
      };

      J = J + K;
     }

     for(I = 1; I < N; I++){
      x[I] = x[I] / N*2;
      y[I] = y[I] / N*2;

     }
        for(I = 1; I < N; I++){

      xx[I] = x[I];
      yy[I] = y[I];

     }

     xx[1] = (double)0.0;
    }
```

Reads the file successfully, but the processing procedure of the FFT is not working.
How to find the FFT procedure, or give the code to check the FFT result?

Answer (score 1):

[here is some free library to do FFT in java](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms).